# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK although min-sdk is met?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got a weird problem. I'm trying to launch an application I wrote on a API-10 (Gingerbread) Emulator, but I keep getting "INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK". I can still install it on devices and Emulator that are running an API-level that is higher than the minSDK I had before. The android-support-library is added so fragments should be supported and that shouldn't be the problem. Even when I cange the minSDKlevel to 1, I can't install it on devices lower than level 16 (minSDK I had before).

I think it's some kind of Android Studio problem not reading in my files correctly or something.

Does someone have an idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: LogCat gives me this message (even though minSdkVersion is set to 8:
W/PackageParser: /data/app/vmdl1695239662.tmp (at Binary XML file line #3): Requires newer sdk version #16 (current version is #10)

Comment: What is the minsdk acutally set in the apk? (use aapt dump badging)

Answer (score 0):

if you sure about your minimum sdk , remove the content of "bin" folder in the project and clean and build again it should work correctly :)